# Solve an equation where the variable is used multiple times: $.5(X)+X=150$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a simple algebra problem where I know the answer but I don't know how to explain to someone how to get to the answer.

The problem is:

$$.5(X)+X=150$$

I know the answer is $X = 100$ but how do I explain that to someone and show the work?

I thought it would $.5(X) = 150-X$ but I don't know the next step?

Comment: combine like terms

Comment: Add to find $1.5 X = 150$.  Then divide both sides by $1.5$.

Comment: THANK YOU! That is exactly what I was looking to say but couldnt think of how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you familiar with the concept of *combining like terms*?

The idea is that (for example) $2x + 5x$ can be combined as $7x$.  This can be formally proved using the distributive property:

> $$2x+5x = (2+5)x = 7x$$

but the idea behind is just that if you have $2$ "things" and then add to that $5$ more "things", the total is $7$ "things".

In your case, you need to combine $.5x$ and $x$.  Complicating things slightly is the fact that $x$ doesn't *seem* to have a coefficient attached to it.  But remember that $x$ is just another way of writing $1x$.

Can you take it from there?